# How do I clear out the ssh-agent entries (on Mac OS X )?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm running Mac OS X, and it appears that after SSHing to several machines, using identity files, my ['ssh-agent'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) builds up a lot of identity / keys and then sometimes offers too many to a remote machine, causing them to kick me off before connecting:

> Received disconnect from 10.12.10.16: 2: Too many authentication failures for cwd

It's pretty obvious what's happening, and [this page](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-and-ssh-agent) talks about it in more detail:

> SSH servers only allow you to attempt
>   to authenticate a certain number of
>   times. Each failed password attempt,
>   each failed pubkey/identity that is
>   offered, etc, take up one of these
>   attempts. If you have a lot of SSH
>   keys in your agent, you may find that
>   an SSH server may kick you out before
>   allowing you to attempt password
>   authentication at all. If this is the
>   case, there are a few different
>   workarounds.

Rebooting clears the agent and then everything works OK again. I can also add this line to my `.ssh/config` file to force it to use password authentication:

```
PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password
```

Anyhow, I saw the note on the page I referenced talking about deleting keys from the agent, but I'm not sure if that applies on a Mac since they appear to be cleared after reboot anyhow.

**Is there a simple way to clear out all keys in the 'ssh-agent' (the same thing that happens at reboot)?**

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Your SSH keys should *not* get automatically added to the agent just because you SSH'ed to a server...

Run `ssh-add -l` to list the agent's keys, `ssh-add -D` to clean out all keys.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the OSX's config? If I type in `ssh-add -l` I get nothing. If I type in `ssh -i ~/keyFileLocation.dsa un@remotehost` I get an OS X popup dialog asking for the passphrase. I type it in and then it connects me. If I disconnect and then type `ssh-add -l` it shows me the identity I just used. After I restart the computer and type `ssh-add -l` it is blank again. `ssh-add -D` worked great to clear out the keys without restarting. Thanks!

Comment: Four years later and this still is an issue, but this fix still works--thank you

Comment: Hey can you guide me for this please? http://superuser.com/questions/951002/ssh-agent-loses-identity-while-restart-machine

Comment: Wrong (in 2017): see the `AddKeysToAgent` configuration option, which is designed for the express purpose of adding your SSH keys to the agent just because you SSH'd to a server.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to limit what keys are checked against is to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to `/.ssh/config` and a list of entries

`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<nameofkey>`

You may also add them to each Host entry:

`Host server-name
  HostName <ipaddress>
  User <username>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<nameofkey>`

[SSH Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) has more options as well.