# How do stop the OpenSSH window from continuously prompting me for my passphrase?

Tags: windows, git, openssh, git-bash

I'm using the git bash terminal on Windows 10 to work with repos. When I use a repo where I used SSH to connect to the remote repo, I get an OpenSSH dialog that requests my passphrase with 'Enter passphrase for key /c/..id_rsa'. The dialog gives me an OK and Cancel button. I press either one, the dialog goes away. It seems to pop up about every 5 to 10 minutes or so. It is driving me nuts.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using VS Code to do my work. VS Code is git aware so it could play into this, or not.

Note that I did set a password for my key so [this post didn't help](https://superuser.com/questions/1010542/how-to-make-git-not-prompt-for-passphrase-for-ssh-key-on-windows).

Is there a setting in my profile that I'm missing?

Comment: find out what process invokes this window.

Comment: @Jakuje, it is the VS Code process that opens the OpenSSH dialog. I'll open an issue against VS Code for this.

Answer (score 0):

I opened Windows *Task manager*, right-clicked on *Wish Application*, went to file location and deleted the *.exe* off my PC. Was the only way that worked for me.